How can I measure virtual memory performance?
I'm trying to optimize the following kernel variables, to favor latency without compromising throughput too much, on a system with an M.2:

vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs

vm.dirty_expire_centisecs

vm.dirty_background_ratio

vm.dirty_ratio

vm.vfs_cache_pressure

ext4 commit frequency


The problem is that each time I run various performance measurement tools I get extremely different results, the variability is huge.
I tried to somehow reduce extreme measurements by using the statistic function "trimean", which does exactly that. But even then every measurement is relatively different.

"system with an M.2"  meaning flash memory on a fast bus for "secondary" storage?

@greybeard Primary internal storage.

PCIe for primary storage? Really? Please elaborate on "M.2" in the question body.

@greybeard I don't understand what is your doubt. M.2 is a storage form factor, with a specific port evolution of SATA.

SATA is for secondary storage: why mention M.2?

@greybeard In case the interface influence how the metrics shall be taken.
